# Создание ECDH в C++ Builder через Openssl

Tags: c++, openssl, криптография

Скачал бинарники [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), через `implib` сделал `lib` из `dll`. Закинул файлы `*.h` в папку `include` builder'a. Создаю приложение, код взят [отсюда](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie_Hellman):

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>

unsigned char *ecdh(size_t *secret_len)
{
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx, *kctx;
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
    unsigned char *secret;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL, *peerkey, *params = NULL;
    /* NB: assumes pkey, peerkey have been already set up */

    /* Create the context for parameter generation */
    if(NULL == (pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_EC, NULL))) handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the parameter generation */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_paramgen_init(pctx)) handleErrors();

    /* We're going to use the ANSI X9.62 Prime 256v1 curve */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_ec_paramgen_curve_nid(pctx, NID_X9_62_prime256v1)) handleErrors();

    /* Create the parameter object params */
    if (!EVP_PKEY_paramgen(pctx, &params)) handleErrors();

    /* Create the context for the key generation */
    if(NULL == (kctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(params, NULL))) handleErrors();

    /* Generate the key */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(kctx)) handleErrors();
    if (1 != EVP_PKEY_keygen(kctx, &pkey)) handleErrors();

    /* Get the peer's public key, and provide the peer with our public key -
     * how this is done will be specific to your circumstances */
    peerkey = get_peerkey(pkey);

    /* Create the context for the shared secret derivation */
    if(NULL == (ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, NULL))) handleErrors();

    /* Initialise */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_init(ctx)) handleErrors();

    /* Provide the peer public key */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer(ctx, peerkey)) handleErrors();

    /* Determine buffer length for shared secret */
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive(ctx, NULL, secret_len)) handleErrors();

    /* Create the buffer */
    if(NULL == (secret = OPENSSL_malloc(*secret_len))) handleErrors();

    /* Derive the shared secret */
    if(1 != (EVP_PKEY_derive(ctx, secret, secret_len))) handleErrors();

    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(peerkey);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(kctx);
    EVP_PKEY_free(params);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);

    /* Never use a derived secret directly. Typically it is passed
     * through some hash function to produce a key */
    return secret;
}
```

Ошибку выдает строка `peerkey = get_peerkey(pkey);` Говорит, что не найдена функция, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: `get_peerkey` - это ваша собственная функция по обмену ключами.

Comment: Спасибо большое за направление, Хотя я немного не понял, я просто хочу создать ключи программно, или функция обмена ключами должна быть заложена в сам ключ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обмен **публичными** ключами (`EC_POINT`) производится через протокол. В случае `SSL`, это происходит на стадиях `ServerKeyExchange` и `ClientKeyExchange`. Но если у Вас какой-то другой протокол, обмен ключами может идти по другому сценарию. В любом случае, Вам нужно доставить эти ключи каждой стороне диалога.

Чтобы создать **приватный** ключ, нужно вызвать `EC_KEY_generate_key`. А чтобы получить "общий секрет" на основе Вашего **приватного** ключа и **публичного** ключа собеседника, нужно вызвать `ECDH_compute_key`.

На обеих сторонах диалога должна быть выбрана одна и та же кривая (`EC_GROUP`), это обязательное условие.

Пример генерации ключа ECDH:

```
key     = EC_KEY_new();
group   = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(curve);
EC_KEY_set_group(key, group);
EC_KEY_generate_key(key);
EC_GROUP_free(group);
```

Comment: До меня немного доходит результат исполнения кода, это сама реализация обмена ключами как я понял, я хотел немного другого, я хотел просто с генерировать ключи, а дальше работу доверить компоненту Indy. Кажется немного глубоко полез

Comment: Добавил пример для генерации ключа, Вам нужно только задать имя кривой (curve), например, тот же `NID_X9_62_prime256v1`. И далее, key можно передавать уже другим компонентам, которые произведут обмен.

Comment: Вы просто застопорились на `get_peerkey`, поэтому я описал в 2-х словах суть этой процедуры тоже.

Comment: Проще использовать для этого чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42669/ecdh--c-builder--openssl